# No browsers available, yet actions requested?

Tags: linux, phantomjs, js-test-driver

I'm getting this error while trying to capture a browser using the JsTestDriver:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No browsers available, yet actions [com.google.jstestdriver.RunTestsAction@5427ee05] requested. If running against a persistent server please capture browsers. Otherwise, ensure that browsers are defined.
    at com.google.jstestdriver.browser.BrowserActionExecutorAction.run(BrowserActionExecutorAction.java:94)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.ActionRunner.runActions(ActionRunner.java:81)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.embedded.JsTestDriverImpl.runConfigurationWithFlags(JsTestDriverImpl.java:342)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.embedded.JsTestDriverImpl.runConfiguration(JsTestDriverImpl.java:233)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.Main.main(Main.java:70)
```

Basically, what I'm doing is the following:

1. Starting the JsTestDriver server with:

   nohup java -jar JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --port 9876 > jstd.out 2> jstd.err < /dev/null &
2. Then I'm trying to capture a browser with:

   nohup ./phantomjs phantomjs-jstd.js > phantomjs.out 2> phantomjs.err < /dev/null &
3. And finally I try to run the tests with:

   java -jar JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --server http://localhost:9876  --config ../../jsTestDriver.conf --tests all

I have to say, that this is happening after I have updated the Ubuntu server I had, from 11.10 to 12.04. It could help to bring some light to the issue I'm experiencing here.

I have no idea about what's going on...

By the way, I have accessed the link http://localhost:9876 and I get this output HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JsTestDriver</title>
    <script>
      function getEl(id){return document.getElementById(id);}function toggle(id) {
if (getEl(id).style.display=='block') {getEl(id).style.display='none';} else {getEl(id).style.display='block';}}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/capture">Capture This Browser</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="/capture?strict">Capture This Browser in strict mode</a>
    <br/>
    <p><strong>Captured Browsers: (0)</strong></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which tells me that there is something wrong since there are no elegible browsers.

**EDIT**

While trying in a different machine (Fedora 21), I have successfully executed everything. The different output I had was when running the second command, the one that attempts to capture a browser. The output I got was this one:

```
Wed Apr 13 2016 12:46:33 GMT+0200 (CEST): Attempting (1) to load: http://localhost:9876/capture
Wed Apr 13 2016 12:46:34 GMT+0200 (CEST): Finished loading http://localhost:9876/capture with status: success
```

And when visiting the URL http://localhost:9876 now I see there is one Captured browser. Still no clue about what happens in the Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got the answer to my own question, after the whole day of trial and error. I have downloaded PhantomJS and replaced the previous binary with the new one. When running PhantomJS, the output was empty, no matter what I did with it. Even "phantomjs --version" made it exit unexpectedly.

The weird thing is that I used that 'corrupted' binary in Fedora 21, which worked as well in Ubuntu 11.10 prior to upgrading that Ubuntu to 12.04.

Problem solved!